# jQuery mobile: Applying style after reloading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

First of all I' very new to jQuery and JavaScript but not to HTML and PHP.

I found many posts about that problem but no solution. I think I am doing something (completely?) wrong...

I've got two files, the index.php and content.php which should dynamically add content to the page.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Ajax test</title>

    <script language="JavaScript">

    $(function(){
        $('#page1').click(function(event) {        
            $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')).trigger("create");
            return false;
        });
    });


    $(function(){
        $('#page2').click(function(event) {        
            $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')).trigger("create");
            return false;
        });
    }); 

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="hm-agenda" data-theme="a" data-role="page">

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h1>Ajax test</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="content" data-role="content">
            Default content
        </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="nav-glyphish-example">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d" class="navdiv">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="content.php?page=1" id="page1">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="content.php?page=2" id="page2">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="content.php?page=3" id="page3">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="content.php?page=4" id="page4">Page 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="content.php?page=5" id="page5">Page 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So a click to "Page 1" or "Page 2" in the navigation should load content.php?page=x into the div with the id "content".

And this is how content.php looks like:

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="hm-list">
<li data-role="list-divider"><h3>You are on page: <?php print $_GET['page']; ?></h3></li>
</ul>
```

Loading the file into the content-div works fine put jQuery won't apply the styling stuff.
The strange thing is that after clicking the link in the navigation the style is getting applied for about one second and disappears immediately.

This example is online at: http://m.sepulturagenda.ch/ajax/

Any help is appreciated. I stock here for hours now...

Comment: hmm seems to be applying style just fine

Comment: are you wanting the button to look pressed in or 'selected' ?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with this line:

```
$('#content').load($(this).attr('href')).trigger("create");
```

You are creating an asynchronous request via `.load()` and not waiting for it to complete before calling the `.trigger("create")` method. So basically you are calling the `.trigger("create")` method before there is any HTML to initialize.

You can utilize the callback function that you can pass to `.load()` to call the `.trigger("create")` method at the correct time.

For example:

```
$(function(){
    $('#page1').click(function(event) {        
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
            $('#content').trigger("create");
        }).trigger("create");
        return false;
    });
});
```

**A Quick Note:**

Is there a reason you're using `.load()` to load external content? jQuery Mobile will do this for you as long as the external content is in the proper format. Here is some documentation to explain what I mean: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

**And a Side Note:**

Using the `document.ready` event handler is not recommended when using jQuery Mobile. Instead you should bind to one of the jQuery Mobile page-events, like `pageinit`.

For example:

```
//place this in the global scope
$(document).on('pageinit', '#my-page', function () {
    $('#page1').click(function(event) {        
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
            $('#content').trigger("create");
        }).trigger("create");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Although since you're using an ID as the selector for your `click` event handler, you might as well delegate the event handler strait to the `#page1` element.

For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#page1', function () {    
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
        $('#content').trigger("create");
    }).trigger("create");
    return false;
});
```

Here is the documentation for jQuery Mobile events (see the large yellow warnings at the top of the page): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Many thanks, that helped!

The reason why I use .load() is because I want to replace just the content of my <div id="content"> and not reload the whole page.
I thought that this gives me the availability to work with slide-effects which just effects the content and not the footer and header of my page. But may thats the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but you could just manually tell it to add the "ui-btn-active" class..

```
 $(function(){
    $('#page2').click(function(event) {  
        $(".ui-btn-active").removeClass("ui-btn-active");   
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')).trigger("create");
        $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
        return false;
    });
});
```